# What does tilde mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

In statistics books, I have seen expressions like:

$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi{( n-1 )}$

In this context, what does the $\sim$ mean?

Comment: "is distributed as".

Comment: By the way, it's normally spelled "tilde".  "Tilda" is a personal name.

Comment: I suspect it is more likely to have been $\chi^2(n-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is used to say that a random variable follows a specific distribution, in this case the Chi distribution with parameter $(n-1)$.